# Combine multiple records to one

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have multiple records that I want to group into a single record.
The multiple records have are having ranges.
The resultant record should just contain the range.
for ex:
In the below example I am having 6 records all having similar data except for colum 5 shown as c5.
The resultant table has 7 columns having the range.
Please request for any assistance to go about this.
Many Thanks,
Gagan

```
    scenario:

    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  
    -----------------------
    AA  BB  CC  DD  1   FF

    AA  BB  CC  DD  2   FF

    AA  BB  CC  DD  3   FF

    AA  BB  CC  DD  4   FF

    AA  BB  CC  DD  5   FF

    AA  BB  CC  DD  6   FF


    result record:

    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7
    --------------------------
    AA  BB  CC  DD  1   6  FF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a group by and a min and max?

Select c1,c2,c3,c4,min(c5), max(c5), c6 from [table]
group by c1,c2,c3,c4,c6

Will that not work for you?

Comment: Thanks, BaconSah,let me try that and get back to you